# SSH Gnome Terminal Background/Foreground Colors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, gnome-terminal, redhat-enterprise-linux

How can I automatically change the background/foreground color of my terminal based on the host that I SSH into?

My current setup is an Ubuntu desktop running Gnome-Terminal that SSHs into a set of RHEL5 hosts. I have an SSH config file that I use to connect to these hosts.

I have searched this site, as well as many others, but haven't been able to get any posted solution to work. So far, I have tried using escape characters, setterm, and tput. Those commands work fine when I am not SSH'd into a machine. As soon as I SSH, however, I loose the set colors. Also, I have messed around with the Gnome-Terminal profile settings, but I'd rather not manually set the profile each time I run SSH.

Comment: Please check this link for more information

http://askubuntu.com/questions/13705/automatically-change-terminal-colors-on-remote-connection

Comment: That is definitely a possibility, but there is one problem with it. If I SSH into machine A, and then SSH into machine B, the terminal has all of my history with machine A will be closed, and I will lose the history.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically set the foreground and background colors by commands such as these:

```
echo -ne '\e]10;red\a'
echo -ne '\e]11;#ffff00\a'
```

I would probably emit these as part of `$PS1` or `$PROMPT_COMMAND` both locally and on the remote servers (with different color on each server). That way when you terminate your `ssh` command, you'll get back to the local color (and it even works as expected via multiple ssh hops).

Comment: Sorry, where do I put this so that it gets run when I exit the ssh?